# setNativeProps for TextInput in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

How do I know what ***native props*** are available for a component to use `setNativeProps`. In this example, the `<TextInput>` component doesn't have `text` as a prop but apparently `setNativeProps` use `text` instead of `value` as a prop. Thank you!

```
clearText = () => {
    this._textInput.setNativeProps({text: ''});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <TextInput
          ref={component => this._textInput = component}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.clearText}>
          <Text>Clear text</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty common in react-native, due to limited documentation. Whenever looking for any information regarding react-native components, it is a good idea to simply look at the .js file you are using. In this case, TextInput, can be found...

```
Project/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/TextInput/TextInput.js
```

Hope you can find what you're looking for - with a bit of digging. If you want to look further, looking into the RCT files is a good idea also.

```
Project/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text/RCTTextField.h
Project/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text/RCTTextView.h
```

Comment: The `RCTTextView.h` has the answer for what I'm looking for. Thanks!